# Координаты tk python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть переменная Coords она ,это координаты канвас изображения.(canvas.create_image) И есть функция, она постоянно изменяет эти координаты(canvas.move). Но проблема в том, что координаты один раз задались, а когда картинка уже в другом месте, функция видит только старые координаты. Допустим: сейчас [255, 600], ее переместил на 100, 100, теперь координаты [355, 700]. Далее обращаюсь к функции, она удваивает координаты и перемешает на результат. Вот: должно быть 355, 700 х 2 = [710, 1400], а он берет только старые координаты и делает: 255, 600 х 2 = [510, 1200]Как решить?

**Часть кода:**

```
Coords = canvas.itemconfig(Mmnemy)
def aCoords():
   print(Coords)

def EnemyGeneration():
   canvas.move(Mmnemy, Coords[0] -Coords[0] + random.randint(80,1130)  , Coords[1] - Coords[1] + random.randint(60,670)) 
   canvas.itemconfig(Mmnemy, state='normal')
# (Сводит координаты к нулю и перемещает на рандомное число, разрешение же 1280х720)

def regenerate(): # (респавнит)
   canvas.move(Mmnemy, Coords[0] -Coords[0] + random.randint(80,1130)  , Coords[1] - Coords[1] + random.randint(60,670)) 
# (Беда именно в регенерейте, она постоянно двигает на одно и то же число, примерно на 200 по x,y, хотя число должно быть постоянно новое)
```

Comment: Добавьте код, демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @insolor Добавил

Comment: Я в общем сильно не вчитывался, но вообще я вспомнил, что move - это относительное перемещение (т.е. вы указываете насколько сдвинуть фигуру относительно исходных координат). Если нужно перемещать на конкретные координаты, используйте метод coords.

Comment: Еще, не знаю в чем смысл конструкции вида `Coords[0] -Coords[0]` - как бы из уроков арифметики можно вспомнить, что если из вычесть одинаковое число само из себя, то получится 0

Comment: @insolor Я на это и рассчитывал, я хотел переместить изображение на ранломное число на экране, поэтому, чтобы число было равно тому, что выпало, я сначала свожу коорд на ноль и плюсую сколько выпало. А типа координаты задавать можно? canvas.coords(m) = "и тут координаты" ? щас проверю, я думал, это только для получения координат

Comment: `cavnas.coords(m, x, y, x + width, y + height)`

Comment: `Coords[0] -Coords[0] + random.randint(80,1130)` => `0 + random.randint(80,1130)` => `random.randint(80,1130)`. В конструкции `Coords[0] -Coords[0]` нет никакого смысла.